# How to squeeze white spaces between sections and figures?

Tags: spacing, formatting

I am using a multicolumns article template for some kind of CV profile. I have all working as intended except of 1 small problem.

In my first column, I have quite some high amount of white space (between bottom of photo and "Profil"), that I don't understand how to remove. You can see an example in the picture below.[image: Column with white space]

The corresponding code is:

```
   \begin{document}
   \setlength{\columnsep}{.25in}
   \begin{multicols}{2}
```

{\LARGE John Doe}\   lorem \   ipsum

\NewPart{Kontakt}

`lorem ipsum

\begingroup

\leftskip 1cm

\includegraphics{foobar}

\rightskip\leftskip
\endgroup

\NewPart{Profil}

\subsection{Berufserfahrung}
\begingroup

\leftskip 0.7cm

{\em (11 months)} Sfoobar    \\ [0.6ex]
{\em (2 months)} Blorem ipsum    \\ [0.6ex]
{\em (3 months)} foo bar \\ [0.6ex]

\rightskip\leftskip

\endgroup`

Is there any way to remove all the spacing beween section and figure (as in the picture below)?

Comment: A full working example with preamble would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

ok, inserting a

`\columnbreak`

a bit downstream gives the column flow as desired :)

Comment: But it may also cause a `\raggedbottom` look of the document? I guess this is fine in a CV. Do you know whether the image `\includegraphics{foobar}` has some whitespace at the bottom that is included due to an over-sized bounding box?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and just used

```
\setlength{\intextsep}{0mm}
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{-15mm}
```

Happens to work fine!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You can highlight code by selecting it and clicking the `{}` button on the toolbar.